# MongoDB upsert with updateMany and an array in the filter

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

The code:

```
await this.tagModel.updateMany(
  { name: { $in: tagsArray } },
  { $inc: { count: 1 } },
  { upsert: true },
);
```

But it will upsert the item without a name value.
I want to increment those tagcounts that are in the tagsArray (which works fine)

And if I can't find it then I want to upsert it with the name value that couldn't be found.

The alternative would be a for loop through the tagsArray and updateOne with an upsert, but that would mean multiple db calls instead of one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what [Model.bulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-bulkWrite) is for.

```
let ops = tagsArray.map( (tag) => { updateOne: {
           filter = {name: tag},
           update = {$inc: {count: 1}},
           upsert = true
}})
tagModel.bulkWrite(ops)
```

Comment: Just as a question tho, in this case with the mapped array it can potentially become too big for my servers RAM, while with a solution where I InsertMany and ignore duplicates and then updateMany, is cheaper in ressources

Comment: If there are that many, slice the list to run them in smaller batches